# How exactly does Wilks' Lambda distribution generalize the Hotelling distribution?

Tags: distributions, t-distribution, hotelling-t2

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks%27_lambda_distribution), Wilks' Lambda distribution generalizes Hotelling's distribution. I am having some problems seeing how this works. I can see how Hotelling's distribution generalizes Student's t-distribution (a RV distributed as Hotelling's law with $p=1$ is just the square of a RV distribution as Student's t), but cannot see how to get to Wilks' Lambda. Is there some setting of the parameters $p,m,n$ such that a RV distributed as Wilks' lambda is some transform of a Hotelling RV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question was about the distributions, not the test, and I think I've figured out the answer: a t-distribution squared has an F(1,n) distribution, which is a Hotelling distribution (up to rescaling by a constant determined by the parameters). I believe one can say that an F(m,n) distribution is the same as a Wilks' $\Lambda(1,m,n)$ distribution, which is the kind of 'generalization' I was looking for. (I guess I'm now enough of an 'expert' to edit the wikipedia page ;)

Comment: I think you're right. This seems to be along the lines of Kshirsagar's Multivariate Analysis - Chapter 8, pp.299--300.

Answer (score 2):

[These NCSU course notes](http://faculty.chass.ncsu.edu/garson/PA765/manova.htm) say

> *Multivariate tests* in contrast to the overall F test, answer the
>   question, "Is each effect
>   significant?" or more specifically,
>   "Is each effect significant for at
>   least one of the dependent variables?"
>   That is, where the F test focuses on
>   the dependents, the multivariate tests
>   focus on the independents and their
>   interactions. These tests appear in
>   the "Multivariate Tests" table of SPSS
>   output. The multivariate formula for F
>   is based not only on the sum of
>   squares between and within groups, as
>   in ANOVA, but also on the sum of
>   crossproducts - that is, it takes
>   covariance into account as well as
>   group means....
>
> *Hotelling's T-Square* is the most common, traditional test where there
>   are two groups formed by the
>   independent variables....
>
> *Wilks' lambda*, U. This is the most common, traditional test where there
>   are more than two groups formed by the
>   independent variables.... The t-test,
>   Hotelling's T, and the F test are
>   special cases of Wilks's lambda....

So I presume that if you take Wilks' lambda, and reduce the number of groups formed by the independent variables to two, then you get something like Hotelling's T-Square.

Comment: With 2 groups, all common multivariate test statistics (Wilks' $\Lambda$, Roy's largest root, Pillai-Bartlett-trace, Hotelling-Lawley-trace, Hotelling's $T^{2}$) are equivalent: they are functions of the largest eigenvalue of $A^{-1} B$, the only eigenvalue $\neq 0$ with 2 groups. They are strictly monotic functions of each other, and give the same $p$-value. Example: http://pastebin.com/Dq9jczE1